# Индексация массивов и их размер в Python

Tags: python, numpy

```
coorAntenn_Norm=np.zeros((32,2))

ttcoorAntenn_Norm=tcoorAntenn_Norm[0:31,0]-coorAntenn[0,0]
```

`ttcoorAntenn_Norm` получается размером 31, а не 32, как я ожидал.

Не могу понять, что происходит. 
Вроде индексация от 0
Буду признателен за подсказки

Comment: приведите в вопросе значения `tcoorAntenn_Norm` и `coorAntenn`

Comment: выше по тексту было   tcoorAntenn_Norm=coorAntenn это все Numpy матрицы 32х2. Но вот  когда вот так 
tcoorAntenn_Norm[0:31,0]-coorAntenn[0,0]  то размер уменьшается до 31

Comment: Za Ars уже ответил на ваш вопрос. Срез `[0:n]` вернет `n`, а не `n+1` элементов. Это справедливо и для Vanilla Python и для Numpy

Comment: Понятно спасибо. а есть механизм чтобы [0:n]  возвращал все таки n+1,  а то ну совсем непревычно

Comment: есть такой способ! `array_name[:n+1]` ;) Честно говоря мне кажется неправильным если `[0:n]`  вернет `n+1` элементов

Comment: Спасибо Большое!!!

Answer (score 2):

Если вы ожидаете 32 элемента, то и запрашивайте 32

Ниже простая проверка работы массивов в питоне

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[0:2]
[1, 2]
```

PS: Замените в tcoorAntenn_Norm[0:**31**,0]